# Asp.Net MVC Displaying two tables in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two tables. One called "persons" the other called "incidents"

In the application, they both have CRUD operations implemented. What I want to do is display both tables next to each other in one view.

There are two controllers. One for "persons" the other for "incidents".

The reason they both have CRUD operations is that I need the user to be able to create person entries and incident entries separately but have both display in sync with each other on the same view. I have tried to use ViewModel for this but keep running into errors. Hence why I am now asking for help.

**The model code is:**

```
 public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Service ID:")]
    public string Service_ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Rank/ Title:")]
    public string Rank { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Initials:")]
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Middle Name:")]
    public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Surname:")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Service:")]
    public string Service { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Corps:")]
    public string Corps { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Unit:")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "DOB::")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Gender:")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address:")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Phone:")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Plate Number:")]
    public string Vehicle_Registration { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Make:")]
    public string Make { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Model:")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Year:")]
    public string Year { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Colour:")]
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "WOF Exp:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime WOF { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "REGO Exp:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime REGO { get; set; }



 public int IncidentId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Event Number")]
    public string Event { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "POC")]
    public string MP { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Incident/ Offence")]
    public string Incident { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Location of Incident")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date/Time of Incident")]
    public DateTime Date_Time { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Role in Incident")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Text")]
    public string IncidentDetail { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "BOR")]
    public string BOR { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Action Taken")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
```

**Persons Context**

```
    public class PersonsContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonsContext (DbContextOptions<PersonsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Persons> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Incidents> Incidents { get; set; }
}
```

**Persons Controller**

```
public class PersonsController: Controller
{
    private readonly PersonsContext _context;

    public PersonsController(PersonsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Persons
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchstring, string searchstring1, string searchstring2, string searchstring3)
    {
        var persons = from m in _context.Persons
                      select m;


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring))
        {
            persons = persons.Where(s => s.Service_ID.Contains(searchstring));

        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring1))
        {
            persons = persons.Where(s => s.First_Name.Contains(searchstring1));

        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring2))
        {
            persons = persons.Where(s => s.Surname.Contains(searchstring2));

        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring3))
        {
            persons = persons.Where(s => s.Vehicle_Registration.Contains(searchstring3));

        }

        return View(await persons.ToListAsync());

    }

    // GET: Persons/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var persons = await _context.Persons
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PersonId == id);
        if (persons == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(persons);
    }

    // GET: Persons/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Persons/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Service_ID,Rank,Initials,First_Name,Middle_Name,Surname,Service,Corps,Unit,DOB,Gender,Address,Phone,Vehicle_Registration,Make,Model,Year,Colour,WOF,REGO")] Persons persons)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(persons);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(persons);
    }

    // GET: Persons/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var persons = await _context.Persons.FindAsync(id);
        if (persons == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(persons);
    }

    // POST: Persons/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Service_ID,Rank,Initials,First_Name,Middle_Name,Surname,Service,Corps,Unit,DOB,Gender,Address,Phone,Vehicle_Registration,Make,Model,Year,Colour,WOF,REGO")] Persons persons)
    {
        if (id != persons.PersonId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(persons);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PersonsExists(persons.PersonId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(persons);
    }

    // GET: Persons/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var persons = await _context.Persons
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PersonId == id);
        if (persons == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(persons);
    }

    // POST: Persons/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var persons = await _context.Persons.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Persons.Remove(persons);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool PersonsExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Persons.Any(e => e.PersonId == id);
    }
}
```

**Incidents Context**

```
    public class IncidentsContext : DbContext
{
    public IncidentsContext (DbContextOptions<IncidentsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MP_EST.Models.Incidents> Incidents { get; set; }
}
```

}

**Incidents Controller**

```
    public class IncidentsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IncidentsContext _context;

    public IncidentsController(IncidentsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Incidents
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Incidents.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Incidents/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var incidents = await _context.Incidents
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IncidentId == id);
        if (incidents == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(incidents);
    }

    // GET: Incidents/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Incidents/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Event,NZDFMP,Incident,Location,Date_Time,Role,IncidentDetail,BOR,Action")] Incidents incidents)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(incidents);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(incidents);
    }

    // GET: Incidents/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var incidents = await _context.Incidents.FindAsync(id);
        if (incidents == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(incidents);
    }

    // POST: Incidents/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Event,NZDFMP,Incident,Location,Date_Time,Role,IncidentDetail,BOR,Action")] Incidents incidents)
    {
        if (id != incidents.IncidentId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(incidents);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!IncidentsExists(incidents.IncidentId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(incidents);
    }

    // GET: Incidents/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var incidents = await _context.Incidents
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IncidentId == id);
        if (incidents == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(incidents);
    }

    // POST: Incidents/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var incidents = await _context.Incidents.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Incidents.Remove(incidents);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool IncidentsExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Incidents.Any(e => e.IncidentId == id);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel Class**

```
    public class ViewDetail
{

    public Persons persons { get; set; }
    public Incidents incidents { get; set; }

}
```

**ViewDetailController**

```
public class ViewDetailController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {


        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below sample code where we can combine two model into single model and then return in view, basically this the concept of View model.

var users = (from u in dbContext.SeekerAccounts join od in dbContext.UserTypes on u.user_type_id equals od.Id_UserType
                             where u.email.Equals(_username) && u.password.Equals(encodepassword)
                             select new {
                                 u.City, u.contact_number, u.Current_Address, u.date_of_birth, u.email,
                                 u.email_notification_active, u.Full_Name,u.gender,u.Home_Phone,u.Id_SeekerAccount,
                                 u.Is_active, u.Location,u.Nationality, u.password, u.registration_date, u.ResumeFileName, u.SMS_notification_active,
                                 u.user_type_id, od.User_Type, od.user_type_name
                             }).FirstOrDefault();
                userProfile.id = users.Id_SeekerAccount;
                userProfile.City = users.City;
                userProfile.userType = users.User_Type;
                userProfile.contact_number = users.contact_number;
                userProfile.Current_Address = users.Current_Address;
                userProfile.date_of_birth = users.date_of_birth;
                userProfile.email = users.email;
                userProfile.email_notification_active = users.email_notification_active;
                userProfile.Full_Name = users.Full_Name;
                userProfile.gender = users.gender;
                userProfile.Home_Phone = users.Home_Phone;
                userProfile.Is_active = users.Is_active;
                userProfile.Location = users.Location;
                userProfile.Nationality = users.Nationality;
                userProfile.registration_date = users.registration_date;
                userProfile.ResumeFileName = users.ResumeFileName;
                userProfile.SMS_notification_active = users.SMS_notification_active;
                userProfile.user_type_id = users.user_type_id;
                Session["UserProfile"] = userProfile;
                if (users != null) { return true; } else { return false; }

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is display both tables next to each other in one
> view.

It doesn't matter how or what you want to do the ultimate thing is presenting it in a better way. I assume your have heard of [dtos and or automapper](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/automapper-in-c-sharp/).
Create a drop to hold both your `person` and `incident` objects. Like this

```
public class PersonAndIncident
{
   IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can either use automapper to map the list you have retrieved from the database in your controller or manually do it

```
public class PersonsController: Controller
{
    private readonly PersonsContext _context;

    public PersonsController(PersonsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchstring, string searchstring1, string searchstring2, string searchstring3)
    {

      PersonAndIncident pAndIn = new PersonAndIncident();
      pAndIn.Persons = personsFromDatabase;
      pAndIn.Incidents = incidentsFromDatabase;
      //.........
      return view(pAndIn);
    }
}
```

Then in your view, your can now get both incidents and persons in one view.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to use the block of code you provided for the controller but it still comes back with errors. I think I just simply lack the skill knowledge to get this to work. I have completed some udemy courses in regards to Asp.Net MVC but none of them really touched on this sort of thing.

Answer (score -1):

As I have seen the code block, there is no view model is mention along with the piece of code where you are consuming the ViewModel to display. As per the above code block we have two model which are consuming separately in both the controller.

Please share the ViewModel code block.

Comment: The question I need answered is, how do I combine the two models into a view model. Reason being is each time I have tried it doesn't work. I have followed many tutorials online but nothing is working. One of the parts that I am struggling with is with the ViewModel Class. List all the {get; sets} in the class from both persons and incidents or do I just list it as "public class Persons Persons {get; set;} and public class Incidents Incidents {get; set;}"

Comment: that's why i asked dear, can show the code block of ViewModel so that i can give you the point where from cause the problem.

Comment: Updated the question with the ViewModel Class

Comment: ViewDetailController is empty because I cannot for the life of me find the code to make it sync both tables and then combine them in a view